# derivation of Consensus-ADMM updates

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

According to Stephen Boyd's [textbook](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) on ADMM, the global variable consensus ADMM updates are given as the following, which is pretty straightforward to understand:

[image]

**However, I've recently seen another variation of the consensus-ADMM updates from [this work](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9147590)**
[image]

I tried very hard to derive the primal updates shown above but I just cannot arrive at the same equation. I wonder if this is the same as global variable consensus ADMM at all?

Comment: I didn't know Arnold Schwarzenegger did maths!

Comment: Which term of the primal update du you mean? The last one?

Comment: yes, the last one